# C++ read the content from two lines of document and store in two variables

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to open a ".txt" file and read the content from the first line and the content from the second line. There are some numbers separated with  a simple "space" on both lines of the ".txt" file.

How can I read the content from the first line and save each number in x[100] and read the content from second line and save each number in y[100]?

PS: I am a beginner.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x[100], y[100], i=0;

    ifstream myfile("something.txt");

    while(myfile >> x[i]) {
        cout << x[i] << "\n";
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in tandem with an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) would be one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, use `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`.

```
std::string line1;
std::getline( myfile, line1 );
std::istringstream s( line1 );
while( i < 100 && s >> x[i] )
{
    cout << x[i] << endl;
    ++i;
}
// Bail out if i == 100 and s is not empty.

// Same for line2 and y (and different i)
```

(Remark: Code replaces your `while` loop.)

Comment: The conditions for  `s >> x[i] && i < 100` should be swapped to avoid a buffer overflow in the case of a line with more than 100 elements.

Comment: Is the figure `100` fixed?

Comment: @binaryBaBa That's what the OP did. Did not care to change it.

Comment: An `istringstream` is not really a file, just a file-like interface (`istream`) wrapped over a string. And your code will be about as fast as mine.